# After Executing two tHiveRow components, first component still writing data while second has started moving that data causing issues

Tags: hive, talend

I have a Talend job that runs 2 tHiveRow components.

The first one loads a staging table with an `INSERT OVERWRITE` statement, data volume is approx 500,000 rows. The second tHiveRow does a `merge` statement to upsert new and changed data.

The first tHiveComponent has a log, so the second tHiveRow component starts

> "On Subjob OK"

Everything finishes and no error is thrown. However, the data in the staging table is newer than the data in the insight table.

The staging table data should all be in the insight table, but some is missing. It seems the first tHiveRow  with the `INSERT OVERWRITE` isn't finished when the second one starts. How can I make sure it is finished before the next one starts?

I tried using "On Subjob OK" and "ON Component OK" to trigger the second job after the first one is finished, but facing the same issue.